# Creating a line from two points

Tags: vectors

Given points **A** and **B**, all I need to do is find the direction vector between the two (so **B** - **A**) then use either point in the equation for a line **r = a + tb**

[image]

Yet when I do that here I dont get the right answer; have I misunderstood something?
(I'm aware parametric form implies $$x=a_1 + tv_1$$

EDIT: I got one of the answers below but the books says it is wrong where

x= 4 - t

y= 1 - 3t

z= 12 + 2t

Comment: Please tell us what you did and what answer you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference vector is
$$
B - A = (8, -11, 20) - (4, 1, 12) = (4, -12, 8) = x_{B-A}
$$
a parameterized version of the line is
$$
x_A + t x_{B-A} = x_A + t (x_B - x_A) = (1-t) x_A + t x_B \quad (t \in \mathbb{R})
$$
You can check that the line goes through $A$ and $B$ (or their vectors $x_A$ and $x_B$) by inserting $t=0$ and $t=1$.

Using the given coordinates we get
$$
x_A + t x_{B-A} = (4,1,12) + t (4,-12,8) = (4t + 4, -12 t + 1, 8t +12)
$$

**Update:**
For the book parameterization
$$
(4-s, 1-3s, 12+ 2s)
$$
where I used $s$ instead of $t$ as parameter to not confuse the two candidate parameterizations, we equate and get
$$
4 -s = 4t + 4 \iff s = -4t \\
1-3s = -12 t + 1 \iff s = 4t \\
12+2s = 8t + 12 \iff s = 4t
$$
Hm.. this is inconsistent. There must be an error somewhere.

$s = 0$ yields $A$, and $s = 4$ gives $(0,-11,20)$ which is not $B$.

I believe the book is wrong. It should read $x = 4 + t$ in the book.

Comment: this is exactly what I got; please refer to my edit

Comment: ah that makes more sense; the book's answer do indeed have contain errors in a few topics